# How do I install python app?

Tags: python

I want to install the app I found on a github page (https://github.com/googlei18n/fontview), how do I do it? I tried opening the 'build.py' file through mac terminal but it doesn't work, as well as pyton luncher- it freezes.

```
Kajas-MacBook-Pro:~ Kaja1$ cd fontview-master
Kajas-MacBook-Pro:fontview-master Kaja1$ cd src
Kajas-MacBook-Pro:src Kaja1$ cd fontview
Kajas-MacBook-Pro:fontview
Kaja1$ python2.7 build.py && ./build/FontView.app/Contents/MacOS/fontview
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'build.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: What exactly did you type in your terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the wrong directory. Change back to the folder `fontview-master` and run the command from there.

Comment: when I do it gives me an error: `Kajas-MacBook-Pro:~ Kaja1$ cd fontview-master
Kajas-MacBook-Pro:fontview-master Kaja1$ python2.7 build.py && ./build/FontView.app/Contents/MacOS/fontview
sh: ./src/third_party/gyp/gyp: No such file or directory`

Comment: How did you clone the git repo? Did you clone it with the `--recursive` option like so:      
`git clone --recursive https://github.com/googlei18n/fontview.git` ?